# How to manage VMs created through azure test drive

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-rm-template

I have a test drive deployed having a cold and a hot instance. It always keeps running two virtual machines after having a test drive. Whenever a new test drive is requested, it creates a third virtual machine. I am confused with it.
This is not the intended behavior. It should have only one running VM and the second one should start for a cold instance when the hot instance is not available.

What could be causing the issue? I have used arm template to deploy test drive.

Here is my template to deploy test drive

```
    {
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "metadata": {
    "_generator": {
      "name": "bicep",
      "version": "0.8.9.13224",
      "templateHash": "15559643551456468043"
    }
  },
  "parameters": {
    "vmName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "TestDriveVM",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The name of you Virtual Machine."
      }
    },
    "adminUsername": {
      "defaultValue":"",
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Username for the Virtual Machine."
      }
    },
    "authenticationType": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "password",
      "allowedValues": [
        "sshPublicKey",
        "password"
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Type of authentication to use on the Virtual Machine. SSH key is recommended."
      }
    },
    "adminPasswordOrKey": {
      "type": "secureString",
      "defaultValue":"",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "SSH Key or password for the Virtual Machine. SSH key is recommended."
      }
    },
    "dnsLabelPrefix": {
      "type": "string",
      
      "defaultValue": "[toLower(format('{0}-{1}', parameters('vmName'), uniqueString(resourceGroup().id)))]",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Unique DNS Name for the Public IP used to access the Virtual Machine."
      }
    },
    "ubuntuOSVersion": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "18.04-LTS",
      "allowedValues": [
        "12.04.5-LTS",
        "14.04.5-LTS",
        "16.04.0-LTS",
        "18.04-LTS"
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The Ubuntu version for the VM. This will pick a fully patched image of this given Ubuntu version."
      }
    },
    "location": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "centralus",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Location for all resources."
      }
    },
    "vmSize": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "Standard_D2ads_v5",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The size of the VM"
      }
    },
    "virtualNetworkName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "vNet",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Name of the VNET"
      }
    },
    "subnetName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "Subnet",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Name of the subnet in the virtual network"
      }
    },
    "networkSecurityGroupName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "SecGroupNet",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Name of the Network Security Group"
      }
    },
       

        "commandToExecute": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "git checkout azure-test-drive 
                        sudo ./deploy.sh",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The command to execute."
      }
    }

  
  },
  "variables": {
    "publicIPAddressName": "[format('{0}PublicIP', parameters('vmName'))]",
    "networkInterfaceName": "[format('{0}NetInt', parameters('vmName'))]",
    "osDiskType": "Standard_LRS",
    "subnetAddressPrefix": "10.1.0.0/24",
    "addressPrefix": "10.1.0.0/16",
    "linuxConfiguration": {
      "disablePasswordAuthentication": true,
      "ssh": {
        "publicKeys": [
          {
            "path": "[format('/home/{0}/.ssh/authorized_keys', parameters('adminUsername'))]",
            "keyData": "[parameters('adminPasswordOrKey')]"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces",
      "apiVersion": "2020-11-01",
      "name": "[variables('networkInterfaceName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "properties": {
        "ipConfigurations": [
          {
            "name": "ipconfig1",
            "properties": {
              "subnet": {
                "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', parameters('virtualNetworkName'), parameters('subnetName'))]"
              },
              "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
              "publicIPAddress": {
                "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses', variables('publicIPAddressName'))]"
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "networkSecurityGroup": {
          "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups', parameters('networkSecurityGroupName'))]"
        }
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups', parameters('networkSecurityGroupName'))]",
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses', variables('publicIPAddressName'))]",
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', parameters('virtualNetworkName'), parameters('subnetName'))]"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups",
      "apiVersion": "2020-11-01",
      "name": "[parameters('networkSecurityGroupName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "properties": {
        "securityRules": [
          {
            "name": "SSH",
            "properties": {
              "priority": 1000,
              "protocol": "Tcp",
              "access": "Allow",
              "direction": "Inbound",
              "sourceAddressPrefix": "*",
              "sourcePortRange": "*",
              "destinationAddressPrefix": "*",
              "destinationPortRange": "22"
            }
          },
           { "name": "UI_443",
            "properties": {
              "priority": 1010,
              "protocol": "Tcp",
              "access": "Allow",
              "direction": "Inbound",
              "sourceAddressPrefix": "*",
              "sourcePortRange": "*",
              "destinationAddressPrefix": "*",
              "destinationPortRange": "443"
            }
            }
          
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",
      "apiVersion": "2020-11-01",
      "name": "[parameters('virtualNetworkName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "properties": {
        "addressSpace": {
          "addressPrefixes": [
            "[variables('addressPrefix')]"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets",
      "apiVersion": "2020-11-01",
      "name": "[format('{0}/{1}', parameters('virtualNetworkName'), parameters('subnetName'))]",
      "properties": {
        "addressPrefix": "[variables('subnetAddressPrefix')]",
        "privateEndpointNetworkPolicies": "Enabled",
        "privateLinkServiceNetworkPolicies": "Enabled"
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', parameters('virtualNetworkName'))]"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses",
      "apiVersion": "2020-11-01",
      "name": "[variables('publicIPAddressName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "sku": {
        "name": "Basic"
      },
      "properties": {
        "publicIPAllocationMethod": "Static",
        "publicIPAddressVersion": "IPv4",
        "dnsSettings": {
          "domainNameLabel": "[parameters('dnsLabelPrefix')]"
        },
        "idleTimeoutInMinutes": 4
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
      "apiVersion": "2021-11-01",
      "name": "[parameters('vmName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "properties": {
        "hardwareProfile": {
          "vmSize": "[parameters('vmSize')]"
          
        },
        "storageProfile": {
          "osDisk": {
            "createOption": "FromImage",
            "managedDisk": {
              "storageAccountType": "[variables('osDiskType')]"
            }
          },
          "imageReference": {
            "publisher": "Canonical",
            "offer": "UbuntuServer",
            "sku": "[parameters('ubuntuOSVersion')]",
            "version": "latest"
          }
        },
        "networkProfile": {
          "networkInterfaces": [
            {
              "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces', variables('networkInterfaceName'))]"
            }
          ]
        },
        "osProfile": {
          "computerName": "[parameters('vmName')]",
          "adminUsername": "[parameters('adminUsername')]",
          "adminPassword": "[parameters('adminPasswordOrKey')]",
          "linuxConfiguration": "[if(equals(parameters('authenticationType'), 'password'), null(), variables('linuxConfiguration'))]"
        
        },
                "priority": "Spot",
                "evictionPolicy": "Deallocate",
                "billingProfile": {
                    "maxPrice": -1
                }

      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces', variables('networkInterfaceName'))]"
      ]
    },
   {
      "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('vmName'),'/installcustomscript')]",
      "apiVersion": "2020-12-01",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/', parameters('vmName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "publisher": "Microsoft.Azure.Extensions",
        "type": "CustomScript",
        "typeHandlerVersion": "2.0",
        "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
        "settings": {
          "commandToExecute": "[parameters('commandToExecute')]"
        }
      }
    }
    ],
  "functions": [

  ],
  "outputs": {
    "adminUsername": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[parameters('adminUsername')]"
    },
    "hostname": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses', variables('publicIPAddressName'))).dnsSettings.fqdn]"
    },
    "sshCommand": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[format('ssh {0}@{1}', parameters('adminUsername'), reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses', variables('publicIPAddressName'))).dnsSettings.fqdn)]"
    }
  }}
```

Thanks

Comment: The issue you are experiencing is related to the configuration of your Test Drive deployment. To troubleshoot this issue, you can start by reviewing the configuration of your ARM template to ensure that it is correctly configured to create and manage the virtual machines for your Test Drive deployment.

Comment: @VenkatV the arm template is creating a single virtual machine only. It does not mention anywhere about the two vms. I have review it several times. There is 1 hot and 1 cold instance explicitly mentioned in their relevant boxes

Comment: @JAMSHAID share your code to analyse

Comment: @NaveenSharma I have updated the question with my script. Could you please have a look at it? Thanks

Comment: @VenkatV I have added my script in the question. Could you please have a look at it?